# If $n > 2$, prove that the order of the multiplicative group of units modulo n, $U_n$, is even.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm struggling with this. I know it is going to use Lagrange's Theorem.  This is what I have so far.

Suppose $|U_n| = k.$ 
This implies $a^k = 1$ for all $a$ in $U_n$ and $|a|$ divides $k$.

Now, what can be said about the order of an element $a$?
I haven't been able to conclude that it's even with what I have, therefore I continued so:
$|\langle a\rangle|$ divides $k$ where $\langle a\rangle$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $a.$

However, I haven't been able to conclude that $|\langle a\rangle|$ is even.

So I tried using this:  an element $a$ is in $U_n$ iff gcd$(a, n) = 1$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use a *pairing* argument. If $x$ is a unit, then so is $-x$. And if $n\gt 2$ they are distinct.

Comment: Where is the $-x$ in the group, $U_4 = \{1, 3\}$? I'm trying to understand this in a small example first.

Comment: Sorry, typo. edited to $U_4$.

Comment: I think you mean $U_4$. If $x=1$, then $-x=3$, if $x=3$, then $-x=1$. The objects $1$ and $3$ are a couple. In today's business-oriented language, we can call them *partners*.

Comment: The example you chose to ask about is perhaps too small to see what happens in general. Look at $U_{10}$ or $U_{11}$.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier if written $x \mapsto n-x$.

Comment: It is easier. I was "compromising" between group-theoretic and number-theoretic viewpoint.

Answer (score 4):

**Yet another hint**: Show that $\{+1,-1\}$ is a subgroup of $U_n$ of order $2$. Now apply Lagrange.

Answer (score 1):

**Different hint**: $|U_n|=\varphi(n)$, the Euler totient function. So you have to prove that for $n \gt 2$ this number is even.